# PHP How to upload multiple videos in one form to vimeo

Tags: javascript, php, input, upload, vimeo

I am struggling with the following:

I want to upload 3 videos in one form to Vimeo. I use a template where with some javascript, some magic happens. I am able to get the template working for one file, but when adjusting the javascript and html/php code, I get the following message: *Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

So what am I trying to do:

Part of the html code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"><font color="#FFFFFF">Upload trailer video file:</font>
    <div class="form__video">
        <label id="trailer"  for="form__video-upload">Upload trailer video</label>
        <input data-name="#trailer" id="form__trailer" name="trailer" class="form__video-upload" type="file" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"><font color="#FFFFFF">Upload full/mixed video file:</font>
    <div class="form__video">
        <label id="fullvideo" for="form__fullvideo">Upload full/mixed video</label>
        <input data-name="#fullvideo" id="form__fullvideo" name="fullvideo" class="form__video-upload" type="file" accept="video/*">
    </div>
</div>
                                        
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"><font color="#FFFFFF">Upload high cam video file:</font>
    <div class="form__video">
        <label id="higcam" for="form__highcam">Upload high cam</label>
        <input data-name="#higcam" id="form__highcam" name="higcam" class="form__video-upload" type="file" accept="video/*">
    </div>
</div>
```

part of the Javascript for the inputs:

```
      $('.form__video-upload').on('change', function() {
        var videoLabel  = $(this).attr('data-name');

        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(videoLabel).text($(this)[0].files[0].name);
        } else {
            $(videoLabel).text('Upload video');
        }
    });
    
    
    $('.form__trailer').on('change', function() {
        var videoLabel1  = $(this).attr('data-name');

        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(videoLabel1).text($(this)[0].files[0].name);
        } else {
            $(videoLabel1).text('Upload trailer video');
        }
    });
    
 
    $('.form__fullvideo').on('change', function() {
        var videoLabel2  = $(this).attr('data-name');

        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(videoLabel2).text($(this)[0].files[0].name);
        } else {
            $(videoLabel2).text('Upload full video');
        }
    });
    
    
    $('.form__highcam').on('change', function() {
        var videoLabel3  = $(this).attr('data-name');

        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(videoLabel3).text($(this)[0].files[0].name);
        } else {
            $(videoLabel3).text('Upload high cam video');
        }
    });
```

And then finally some code when submitting (I don't think the error is in this, because when I comment it, the error remains:

```
//if trailer file is filled/selected
if (!empty($_FILES['trailer']['name'])) {
    //adjust name to trailer
    $trailername = $basename." - Trailer";
    $filetrailer = $_FILES['trailer']['name'];
    $filetrailertmp = $_FILES['trailer']['tmp_name'];
                            
    // vimeo upload code
    $uri = $client->upload($filetrailertmp, array(
        "name" => $trailername,
        "description" => $_POST["vDescription"],
        "privacy.view" => 'anybody',
        "privacy.embed" => 'public',
    ));
    $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=transcode.status');
    if ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'complete') {
        print 'Your trailer video finished transcoding.<br>';
    }
    elseif ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'in_progress'){
        print 'Trailer video uploading done. (your video is still processing. please try again to access your video after a few minutes)<br>';
    }
    else {
        print 'Your trailer video encountered an error during transcoding.<br>';
    }
    //retrieve ID for trailer                       
    $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=link');
    $videolinktrailer = $response['body']['link'];
    $get_vid_id_trailer = explode("/",$videolinktrailer);
    $get_vid_id_trailer = $get_vid_id_trailer['3'];
} else { 
    echo "No trailer file selected<br>"; 
}
                        
//if full/mixed video file is filled/selected
if (!empty($_FILES['fullvideo']['name'])) {
    //adjust name to trailer
    $fullvideoname = $basename." - Full/Mixed Video";
    $filefullvideo = $_FILES['fullvideo']['name'];
    $filefullvideotmp = $_FILES['fullvideo']['tmp_name'];
                            
    // vimeo upload code
    $uri = $client->upload($filefullvideotmp, array(
        "name" => $fullvideoname,
        "description" => $_POST["vDescription"],
    ));
    $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=transcode.status');
    if ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'complete') {
        print 'Your full/mixed video finished transcoding.<br>';
    }
    elseif ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'in_progress'){
        print 'Full/mixed video uploading done. (your video is still processing. please try again to access your video after a few minutes)<Br>';
    }
    else {
        print 'Your full/mixed video encountered an error during transcoding.<Br>';
    }
    //retrieve ID for full video                       
    $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=link');
    $videolinkfull = $response['body']['link'];
    $get_vid_id_fullvideo = explode("/",$videolinkfull);
    $get_vid_id_fullvideo = $get_vid_id_fullvideo['3'];
} else { 
    echo "No full/mixed file selected<br>"; 
}
                        
//if high cam video file is filled/selected
if (!empty($_FILES['higcam']['name'])) {
    //adjust name to trailer
    $highvideoname = $basename." - High Cam Video";
    $filehighvideo = $_FILES['higcam']['name'];
    $filehighvideotmp = $_FILES['higcam']['tmp_name'];
                            
    // vimeo upload code
    $uri = $client->upload($filehighvideotmp, array(
        "name" => $$highvideoname,
        "description" => $_POST["vDescription"],
    ));
    $response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=transcode.status');
    if ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'complete') {
        print 'Your high cam video finished transcoding.<br>';
    }
    elseif ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'in_progress'){
        print 'High cam video uploading done. (your video is still processing. please try again to access your video after a few minutes)<Br>';
    }
    else {
    print 'Your high cam video encountered an error during transcoding.<Br>';
    }
//retrieve ID for full video                       
$response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=link');
$videolinkhigh = $response['body']['link'];
$get_vid_id_highvideo = explode("/",$videolinkhigh);
$get_vid_id_highvideo = $get_vid_id_highvideo['3'];
} else { 
    echo "No high cam file selected<br>"; 
}
```

As mentioned, I tried to fill in the form, but it resulted in the error explained above.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have the idea that it has to do with the link of the id of the input vs the java script, I am not that certain that the adjustments in the javascript are made correctly. The first part of the javascript is the original one, I have adjusted them for the three fields.

Comment: What happens if you scale everything down to remotely uploading just one, file which is already on your server? For example, let's call the file `myvid.mp4`. Let's assume that the file is already on your server. Can you upload it to Vimeo with your current PHP code?

Comment: If I add just one file (and clean all code other than that), it works perfectly. However when adding 2 or three it is no longer working anymore.

Comment: Does the remote API return any errors or status codes (particularly, these: 400, 401, 403, 405, 406, 413, 415, 429) ? What happens if you try to work with three files already on the server (`vid_1.mp4`, `vid_2.avi`, `vid_3.webm`), and use a delayed loop for remote uploading? For example, once the previous video finishes uploading, `sleep` for 1-2 seconds, and continue uploading. Also, can you verify that your files are getting from the frontend to your server, before being passed on to Vimeo?

Comment: I found out via the PHP ini that the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size setting was set to 512M, The files were bigger than that. I will check and come back if this was the solution. Not sure if that relates to posting towards Vimeo API though....